# Using a generation function

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am working on my combinatorics hw and there's something I am not quite sure:

Use a generating function for modeling the number of different election
outcomes in an election for class president if 25 students are voting among
four candidates. Which coefficient do we want?

I know how to find the generating function, but I am not sure about which coefficient we want. for generating function, I got

$$g(x) = (1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{25})^4$$

So if we expand the equation, we'd get a bunch of coefficients, but I am not sure which want is what we want and why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "election outcome".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to look at this problem is to see that it is like assigning $25$ balls to $4$ different bins without restriction. The number of ways to do this is $$\binom{25+4-1}{25} = 3276$$
If we wanted to use a generating function, we have that a "box" (candidate) gets filled with either $0, 1, ... 25$ "balls" (votes) so we have $$f(x) = (1+x+x^2+...+x^{25})^4$$
The answer is the coefficient of $x^{25}$ since we have $25$ votes in total. This gives the same answer as before, $3276$

[Expanded function on WolframAlpha](http://expand%20(sum%20from%20i=0%20to%2025%20of%20(x%5Ei)%20)%20%5E4)

Comment: There are some built-in functions one can use to find the precise coefficient: [Coefficient[Sum[x^i, {i, 0, 25}]^4, x^25]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Coefficient%5BSum%5Bx%5Ei,+%7Bi,+0,+25%7D%5D%5E4,+x%5E25%5D) (unfortunately, a "plain English" query like "coefficient of x^25 in expansion of blah" fails to get parsed)

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)